# Python: Variable doesn't update until entire notebook is run or code is finished executing

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, global-variables, ipython

The global variable `selected_options` only updates after the code is finished executing. If you run the following code, `selected_options` will return empty, however if you then run `selected_options` again in another cell below it, it does populate.

I've noticed the variable only populates when the code is finished executing so if I run the entire notebook, it won't have any values until all cells have run. I need to use the values in `selected_options` for other parts of my code later on.

Can someone please explain why this is happening and how to fix? Thank you

```
import ipywidgets as widgets
from IPython.display import display, clear_output

options = ['Option 1', 'Option 2', 'Option 3']
checkboxes = [widgets.Checkbox(description=option) for option in options]
checkboxes_container = widgets.VBox(checkboxes)
display(checkboxes_container)

selected_options = []

def show_selected_options(option):
    global selected_options
    if option['new']:
        selected_options.append(option['owner'].description)
    else:
        selected_options.remove(option['owner'].description)

for checkbox in checkboxes:
    checkbox.observe(show_selected_options, 'value')

while True:
    user_input1 = input("Enter 'done' ")
    if user_input1 == 'done':
        break
    else:
        selected_options.append(user_input1)


print(selected_options) #shows up empty
```

Comment: When you run this code, what do you type at the `Enter 'done' ` input prompt?

Comment: @JohnGordon I select the options from the checkboxes, then enter 'done' in the textbox -- i added this section so the user has time to make their selections before the next cells are executed

Comment: I'm not an expert on IPython widgets, but I suspect the kernel can't actually respond to your checkbox interactions while it's busy running a cell.